# Updates to Database don't Show in the Datagrid Unless I Step Through Code

Tags: c#

This is the same app I've asked about before. I have an Access database and I am using a data adapter, data table, OleDbCommandBuilder, a data grid and some text boxes to show one row from the database. The data grid's datasource is set to the data table: 
DataGrid1.DataSource = dTable; What ever I do to the database, it is reflected in the data grid automatically.

I have a button to run some test code to use my own sql commands to make a conditional change to a record in the database. I am using a connection object and the following method to create and execute my commands:

```
dAdapter.UpdateCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
dAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql;
dAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
dTable.Clear(); 
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
dataGrid1.DataSource = dTable;
```

Here is the kicker, if I set a break point and step through the code, when I get back to the Form the Grid shows the update and if I move the text boxes to the record that was changed, it shows the change / update. If I get rid of the break point and run the app the grid nor the text boxes will reflect the change. If I hit button again to run the same code again, then it will reflect everything. Or if I close the app and run it again it will show the changes. If I set a break point again and run to the break point and step through a few lines and then F5 to run through, the changes will be reflected in the grid and text boxes. If I run to that same break point and then just hit F5 to continue, then the grid and text boxes will not show the changes just as if I had just run the app normally.

I have tried using the grid's refresh and setting the source to null and then back to the data table. Nothing works! Arrrrgggggg! It seems to be a refresh issue being that it works when I step through the code. Although the text boxes are not reflecting the changes either. But something is different when stepping through the code than from running it normally.

Can any one help with this please?

Thanks!

Comment: No one seems to want to touch this one... :) This appears to be a timing issue. The execution of the query takes enough time that the code following the execution line is being executed by C# before the query command is finished and therefore not displaying the changes to the database when the data adapter fills the data table.  You may not like this statement, but this seems incredibly stupid of Microsoft at first glance. If I put a messagebox right after the dAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); everything works running without stepping through the code in debug.

Comment: But if I hit ok on the message box too fast then it does not show the updated database. With this said, does anybody know of any methods, events or properties of the data adapter that could be used to halt code execution until the query is finished????????